# Static IP connection after bare metal install of 20.04

Tags: networking, server, usb-installation

Problem: Convert boot-up to Static IP Address instead of DHCP on New Ubuntu 20.04 install.

First, I'm a newbie and thought I would learn Ubuntu by installing it on a second PC I have on my home network. So I've been trying for the past 2 weeks, but continue to face connectivity issues.

My second PC has an ethernet cable to my router and the router says the PC has the Static IP address 10.0.0.200. I also created a bootable USB-Drive with an ISO image and Install package for Ubuntu Server 20.04.

After booting the new PC, installing Ubuntu with the USB thumb drive (I've done it at least 3 times now), wiping out HD, I notice when I login, it still says:

"IPv4 address for eno1: 10.0.0.202".

In fact, if I install it again - it will now show 10.0.0.203. (It'll add 1 to the address).

How do I change the Network Configuration so it comes up as connected to 10.0.0.200?

I see in the documentation that the installer defaults to a DHCP connection so it can get any updates. Do I now need to change it to a Static connection?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's often simpler to login to your router, and have your router assign a consistent IP address to your Ubuntu system's MAC address.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I login to the router (via administrator) and change the address from 10.0.0.200 to 10.0.0.202 - I get "Alert! Failure! Please check your inputs". I'll now try calling technical support for my carrier and see why I can't change it...

Comment: Alternately, you can set up a static IP address by changing your Netplan config. See https://netplan.io/examples/#using-dhcp-and-static-addressing for an example.

Comment: Thanks. That may be faster (and less painful) then trying to get thru to my ISP.  :)

Comment: Worked! Thanks user535733. I used Netplan config and set the Static IP in the yaml file, applied the changes, and rebooted. My connectivity is now via the Static IP and no longer via the DHCP.  Thanks for your help!